# Optimizing python script with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, web-crawler, web-scraping, python-multithreading

Hello Guys! I have written small web page crawler functions. But I am new to multithreading, I could not optimize it. My code is:

```
alreadySeenURLs = dict() #the dictionary of already seen crawlers
candidates = set() #the set of URL candidates to crawl

def initializeCandidates(url):

    #gets page with urllib2
    page = getPage(url)

    #parses page with BeautifulSoup
    parsedPage = getParsedPage(page)

    #function which return all links from parsed page as set
    initialURLsFromRoot = getLinksFromParsedPage(parsedPage)

    return initialURLsFromRoot 

def updateCandidates(oldCandidates, newCandidates):
    return oldCandidates.union(newCandidates)

candidates = initializeCandidates(rootURL)

for url in candidates:

    print len(candidates)

    #fingerprint of URL
    fp = hashlib.sha1(url).hexdigest()

    #checking whether url is in alreadySeenURLs
    if fp in alreadySeenURLs:
        continue

    alreadySeenURLs[fp] = url

    #do some processing
    print url

    page = getPage(url)
    parsedPage = getParsedPage(page, fix=True)
    newCandidates = getLinksFromParsedPage(parsedPage)

    candidates = updateCandidates(candidates, newCandidates)
```

As one can see, here it takes one url from candidates at specific time. I wanted to make this script multithreaded, in such a way, that it could take at least N urls from candidates, and do the job. Can anyone guide me? Give any links or suggestions?

Comment: There are numerous tutorials on threading on web, just Google "python thread tutorial". Tutorial on Threads Programming with Python(https://users.info.unicaen.fr/~fmaurel/documents/envrac/python/PyThreads.pdf) is one very good tutorial for absolute beginners.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with these two links:

1. The basic reference for threading in Python
   http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html
2. A tutorial where they actually implement a multithreaded URL crawler in python
   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/

Moreover, you already have a crawler for python: http://scrapy.org/